# axios post server does not receive data from browser

Tags: axios

I am using axios.post but the server does not seem to receive the post-data.

This is what I have:

```
var baseURL = "http://localhost:8888/dbRouting.php";
var body = {
  function: 'foo',
  id: 'bar',
}

axios.post(baseURL, body)
.then((response) => { console.log( "Data Loaded AXIOS: " + response.data ); })
.catch(function (error) {console.log(error);});

// Data Loaded AXIOS: array(0) {
// }
```

This jQuery post to the same file, on the other hand, works:

```
$.post( baseURL, body )
  .done(function( data ) {
     console.log( "Data Loaded JQUERY: " + data );
  });

//Data Loaded JQUERY: array(2) {
//["function"]=>
//string(3) "foo"
//["id"]=>
//string(3) "bar"
//}
```

The server file (dbRouting.php) is just:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

This is my way of allowing the back-end which is php to process it via $_POST. This is part of my code in vue inside method section.

Assuming you are post it to a post_url and you have an object, var myObject:

```
var myObject = {
  property: value,
  property1: value1,
  property2: value2
}
```

Inside my vue, method section:

```
 updateForm: function( myObject ){
            var post_url = (your post url);

            axios.post(post_url, makePostReady( myObject ) )
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
             })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
             });
      }
```

Then above(before axios post call) or make it a global function. I created below function to turn any object I want to send as post using axios so that it will form

```
property=value&poperty1=value1&property2=value2......
```

Below is the function:

```
function makePostReady( object )
{
    var sentence = "";
    for (var key in object) {
        sentenceAdd = key + '=' + object[key] + '&';
        sentence = sentence + sentenceAdd;
    }
    //console.log( 'sentence: ' + sentence );
    return sentence;
}
```

After that you can var_dump( $_POST ) at your post_url to check if everything is fine. Then you can process the data as usual.

Hopefully it helps

Below is some picture to help understanding better

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems a networking issue. 
Double check the URL and the port localhost:8888/dbRouting.php on JQuery & Axios demo
Are they exactly the same?
Is your .catch fired on axios? What's the error?
is your server responding on localhost:8888?

Alternatively, you can check your server implementation using a different client (e.g. Postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

Comment: URL and port double checked. The php file is accessed in both cases. axios works fine (no errors thrown) and `then` is triggered. It's just that the php file does not receive any data from axios' post-call. Everything else works tiptop.

Comment: I'm having the same problem too